# How to upgrade existing SharePoint entrprise search to FAST Search

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Currently we have migrated MOSS 2007 site to SharePoint 2010 using In-Place upgrade. However we would like to upgrade existing search to fast search, anyone know the procedure to upgrade from exisitng search to FAST search.

Thanks 
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Fast Search for Sharepoint involves a complete separate product that is installed and linked up to Sharepoint 2010. First you need to get binaries/licences etc.

Once you get that, you can check out the technet documentation at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381243.aspx

Or if you dont want to install it yourself you can get MS or a partner to install/customize for you.